# One record per page in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder 3.0 i have created a table displaying information about a list of employees in an organization. The idea is to have one page per employee. The employees can be selected from a drop-down in the report and selecting multiple employees should result in one page per employee. Right now my table is expanding including the information for all selected employees in the same table. Can i make the table only include records from one employee, break to the next page and repeat the table on this page with the next employee?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120823/ssrs-report-structure/9121539#9121539) yesterday may help.

The report won't repeat; the table won't repeat; but you can have rows of the table repeat. You can set the report up to have a page break before every row or you can [create groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220417.aspx) of rows that are displayed on separate pages.

To answer your question directly and specifically:

> Can i make the table only include records from one employee, break to the next page and repeat the table on this page with the next employee?

Yes, you can make the table only include records from one employee, and you can include page breaks. No you can not repeat the same table in the same report without executing the report multiple times. One way to do this is by using a subreport. Take a look at the answer I typed up yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Use a List.  Make it the size of your page.  When you click on the center of the list, it will give you Rectangle properties.  Set PageBreak = end.  Make sure Disabled = False.